# Customizing playback controls in a Leanback app

Tags: android, android-videoview, android-tv, leanback

I have a pretty basic task: implementing HLS video streaming using Leanback framework and Exoplayer.

I use a simple single-fragment layout:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<FrameLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <fragment
        android:id="@+id/video_fragment"
        android:name="android.support.v17.leanback.app.VideoFragment"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent" />

</FrameLayout>
```

Apparently, `VideoFragment` comes with a default HUD which looks like this:

[image]

According to the docs, the recommended approach to bridging media player with playback controls is via `PlaybackGlue`. For example, Leanback showcase app uses `MediaPlayer` and thus uses a `MediaPlayerGlue`. I, for my purposes, have taken `ExoPlayerGlue` from [this](https://github.com/irtimmer/itplayer/blob/master/app/src/main/java/nl/itimmer/itplayer/player/ExoPlayerGlue.java) project.

```
private PlaybackFragmentGlueHost glueHost;
private PlaybackControlGlue glue;

@Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    // ...

    final VideoFragment videoFragment = (VideoFragment) getFragmentManager.findFragmentById(R.id.video_fragment);
    glueHost = new VideoFragmentGlueHost(videoFragment);

    glue = ExoPlayerGlue(this, player)
    glue.setHost(glueHost);
}
```

This code does the job: it binds clicks to player events, so pause/resume and rewinding/fast-forwarding work as expected.

The tricky part is customizing playback controls. `PlaybackGlueHost` provides `setPlaybackRow(Row row)` and `setPlaybackRowPresenter(PlaybackRowPresenter presenter)` methods. Worth pointing out is that these methods have no effect in `onCreate()` so I either have to use handler or move them to `onPostCreate()`:

```
@Override
public void onPostCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onPostCreate(savedInstanceState);

    // Buttons I need in my HUD
    final Action skipPreviousAction = new PlaybackControlsRow.SkipPreviousAction(this); // |<
    final Action rewindAction = PlaybackControlsRow.RewindAction(this); // <<
    final Action playPauseAction = PlaybackControlsRow.PlayPauseAction(this);
    final Action fastForwardAction = PlaybackControlsRow.FastForwardAction(this); // >>
    final Action skipNextAction = PlaybackControlsRow.SkipNextAction(this); // >|
    final Action repeatAction = PlaybackControlsRow.RepeatAction(this);

    final PresenterSelector controlPresenterSelector = ControlButtonPresenterSelector();
    final PlaybackControlsRow playbackControlsRow = PlaybackControlsRow();

    final ArrayObjectAdapter primaryAdapter = ArrayObjectAdapter(controlPresenterSelector);
    final ArrayObjectAdapter secondaryAdapter = ArrayObjectAdapter(controlPresenterSelector);

    // First row
    primaryAdapter.add(skipPreviousAction);
    primaryAdapter.add(rewindAction);
    primaryAdapter.add(playPauseAction);
    primaryAdapter.add(fastForwardAction);
    primaryAdapter.add(skipNextAction);

    // Second row
    secondaryAdapter.add(repeatAction);

    playbackControlsRow.primaryActionsAdapter = primaryAdapter;
    playbackControlsRow.secondaryActionsAdapter = secondaryAdapter;

    // Applying row to glue host
    glueHost.setPlaybackRowPresenter(PlaybackControlsRowPresenter());
    glueHost.setPlaybackRow(playbackControlsRow);
}
```

Now I have my customized playback row but **the player no longer responds to button clicks**.

I'm having a hard time trying to figure out how `PlaybackGlue` actually reacts to events from a `PlaybackGlueHost`. I know I can set `OnActionClickedListener` in a row presenter and handle actions manually but it kind of renders glue/host interaction model useless. How did it work in the first place? There is no default playback row I could find... I see that each `Action` corresponds to a set of key codes but I'm not sure what I can make of it.

Could anyone point me in the right direction? There's surprisingly little information on the subject.

Thanks.

Comment: do you know how to add custom controls like - report, add to playlist, etc.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Turned out `PlaybackControlGlue` had all the necessary methods (`setControlsRow()`, `onCreatePrimaryActions()`, `onCreateSecondaryActions()`) which I totally missed in the implementation I borrowed. The glue takes care of providing them to its host in `onAttachedToHost()` and then sets neccessary listeners.